# npm start not working for my react project

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So I'm trying to run the npm start on a react project I made in command line so that I can run the browser sync and see my progress as I work on it.

However, I keep getting this result whenever I try to run it.

```
module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/Sam/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Work/BookStore/Home attempts/Routing/2-react-router/lib/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-tutorials@0.0.0 start: `node lib/server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-tutorials@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Sam/.npm/_logs/2017-11-30T20_10_07_869Z-debug.log
```

I'm not sure what's going on as I'm not an expert on react/node/npm, rather a reluctant amateur.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is there actually a `server.js` file in that folder?

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `npm start`, a command `node lib/server.js` is called. Command is defined in package.json

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "node lib/server.js"
}
```

Looking from the error post it looks that `server.js` file is missing in `lib` folder.